# Print Time Slot In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

The problem is that when I'm taking the current time using `localdate`(this is my start time) variable and I'm also taking end time so I print the time between this values with 15 min of increasing time.

Example: current time is 13:04 so the further time slots will be 13:19, 13:34 and so on till end time.

```js
function ShowLocalDate() {
  var time1 = new Date();
  var time2 = new Date();
  var dNow = new Date();
  var localdate = dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes();

  //meeting length
  var meetingLength = parseInt('15');

  //start time 
  var startTime = localdate
  var startHour = startTime.split(':')[0];
  var startMin = startTime.split(':')[1].replace(/AM|PM/gi, '');

  //end time
  var endTime = '11:00 PM';
  var endHour = endTime.split(':')[0];
  var endMin = endTime.split(':')[1].replace(/AM|PM/gi, '');

  //Check if start time is PM and adjust hours to military
  if (startTime.indexOf('PM') > -1) {
    if (startHour != 12) {
      startHour = parseInt(startHour) + 12;
    } else {
      startHour = parseInt(startHour);
    }
    console.log(startHour);
  }

  //Check if end time is PM and adjust hours to military
  if (endTime.indexOf('PM') > -1) {
    endHour = parseInt(endHour) + 12;
    console.log(endHour);
  }

  //Date API start time
  time1.setHours(parseInt(startHour));
  time1.setMinutes(parseInt(startMin));

  //Date API end time
  time2.setHours(parseInt(endHour));
  time2.setMinutes(parseInt(endMin));

  //Adding meeting length to start time, this value will be use for end    time
  time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + meetingLength);

  while (time1 < time2) {
    $('#etime').append('<option value="' + time1 + '">' + time1 + '</option>');
    time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + meetingLength);
  }
}
ShowLocalDate();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select name="etime" id="etime">
      <option value="">--Select end time--</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</tr>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6n458ze9/18/

But I want that, suppose the start time means current time is 13:04 so the next time will be 13:20 not 13:19 and one more time is 13:35 not 13:34, till ending time.

End time will be 11:00 PM(this is fixed).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you mean is that you want to round the "current time" to :05, :10, and such?

Comment: If the end time is fixed at 11:00 pm, and the increment is 15 minutes, it would need to end up on the `:00, :15, :30, :45` cycle, which is not consistent with what you've said about rounding to `13:20`. Should the second time be `13:15`, or should there be logic to "spread out" the difference across multiple increments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just round off the start time in your code.

in below solution i am doing the same.

hope this helps

```js
function getRoundOffDate() {
  var now = new Date();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  minutes += 5 - minutes % 5;
  if (minutes == 60) {
    now.setHours(now.getHours() + 1);
    now.setMinutes(0);
  } else {
    now.setMinutes(minutes);
  }
  return now;
}

function ShowLocalDate() {
  var time1 = new Date();
  var time2 = new Date();
  var dNow = getRoundOffDate();

  var localdate = dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes();

  //meeting length
  var meetingLength = parseInt('15');

  //start time 
  var startTime = localdate
  var startHour = startTime.split(':')[0];
  var startMin = startTime.split(':')[1].replace(/AM|PM/gi, '');

  //end time
  var endTime = '11:00 PM';
  var endHour = endTime.split(':')[0];
  var endMin = endTime.split(':')[1].replace(/AM|PM/gi, '');

  //Check if start time is PM and adjust hours to military
  if (startTime.indexOf('PM') > -1) {
    if (startHour != 12) {
      startHour = parseInt(startHour) + 12;
    } else {
      startHour = parseInt(startHour);
    }
    console.log(startHour);
  }

  //Check if end time is PM and adjust hours to military
  if (endTime.indexOf('PM') > -1) {
    endHour = parseInt(endHour) + 12;
    console.log(endHour);
  }

  //Date API start time
  time1.setHours(parseInt(startHour));
  time1.setMinutes(parseInt(startMin));

  //Date API end time
  time2.setHours(parseInt(endHour));
  time2.setMinutes(parseInt(endMin));

  //Adding meeting length to start time, this value will be use for end    time
  time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + meetingLength);

  while (time1 < time2) {
    $('#etime').append('<option value="' + time1 + '">' + time1 + '</option>');
    time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + meetingLength);
  }
}
ShowLocalDate();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select name="etime" id="etime">
      <option value="">--Select end time--</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</tr>
```

Comment: thank you sir, works now perfectly, but if i'm only want the time means 16:40(not date or anything else) so what is the code for that or what is the specific method for that.

Comment: if you want to show only hours and minutes, than you can replace `time1` with `time1.getHours()+':'+time1.getMinutes()`  in `$('#etime').append('<option value="' + time1 + '">' + time1 + '</option>');` this code line

Comment: Again thank you, but why this method does not print the starting 0 value means the original value is 17:05 but it prints the value 17:5 why?

Comment: cause we are getting minutes separately, you can append the `0` if min length is 1 i.e. `var minutes = dateObj.getMinutes();
minutes = minutes.length == 1? "0" + minutes: minutes;`

Comment: try this one `('<option value="' + ('00' + time1.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + time1.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + '">' + ('00' + time1.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + time1.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + '</option>');`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to round up time to 05, 10, 15 etc minutes you can easily add few more minutes to original time until you get minutes mod by 5 equals zero, something like this

```
  //Adding meeting length to start time, this value will be use for end    time
  var endTime = time2.getMinutes() + meetingLength;

    while (endTime % 5 != 0)  
        endTime++

time1.setMinutes(endTime);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but this take previous values also, example: suppose the current time is 16:34, so it takes 16:15 or 16:30, how can i eliminate this values. again thank you

Answer (score 0):

If end time is fixed to 11:00PM, then you can start from backwards

```js
function ShowLocalDate() {
  var time1 = new Date();
  var time2 = new Date();
  var dNow = new Date();
  var localdate = dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes();

  //meeting length
  var meetingLength = parseInt('15');

  //start time 
  var startTime = localdate
  var startHour = startTime.split(':')[0];
  var startMin = startTime.split(':')[1].replace(/AM|PM/gi, '');

  //end time
  var endTime = '11:00 PM';
  var endHour = endTime.split(':')[0];
  var endMin = endTime.split(':')[1].replace(/AM|PM/gi, '');

  //Check if start time is PM and adjust hours to military
  if (startTime.indexOf('PM') > -1) {
    if (startHour != 12) {
      startHour = parseInt(startHour) + 12;
    } else {
      startHour = parseInt(startHour);
    }
    console.log(startHour);
  }

  //Check if end time is PM and adjust hours to military
  if (endTime.indexOf('PM') > -1) {
    endHour = parseInt(endHour) + 12;
    console.log(endHour);
  }

  //Date API start time
  time1.setHours(parseInt(startHour));
  time1.setMinutes(parseInt(startMin));

  //Date API end time
  time2.setHours(parseInt(endHour));
  time2.setMinutes(parseInt(endMin));
  time2.setSeconds(0);

  //Adding meeting length to start time, this value will be use for end    time
  time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + meetingLength);

  while (time1 < time2) {
    $('#etime option:first').after('<option value="' + ('00' + time2.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + time2.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + '">' + ('00' + time2.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + time2.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + '</option>');
    time2.setMinutes(time2.getMinutes() - meetingLength);
  }
  $('#etime option:first').after('<option value="' + ('00' + time1.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + time1.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + '">' + ('00' + time1.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + time1.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + '</option>');
}
ShowLocalDate();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select name="etime" id="etime">
      <option value="">--Select end time--</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</tr>
```